# Change Reference DLL at build time

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reference, build-process

I have a project which creates custom SSIS tasks.   Each version of SQL server requires a different [DTS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.pipeline.wrapper.aspx) Dll reference.

> Sql 2008 - 100
>  Sql 2012 - 110 
> Sql 2014 - 120 
> ....

For me to build my application to support the diffrent versions of SQL server the code needs to be slightly different for that I was going t use  [Predecessor directives](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx)

What I haven't figured out how to do is how to change the Dlls referenced when i build the different versions.

Is it possible to to change reference dlls at build time? If so how?

*Note: Currently we have a build script which copies the project does a bunch of fancy string replaces and and changes the reference.  This does work but personally I find it ugly.*

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work, but give it a go:

- Local copy all the required dependencies for all versions of MS SQL server. In run-time resolve the version and load corresponding dll, or
- Create a build time variable that defines the version of the dependent variable. Add a reference to one library, for example, 2008. Edit C# project file manually and replace the reference to 2008 with your build-time variable. Now by changing the build time variable, you will be able to control which library is used.

Comment: ohhh this sounds like an interesting idea.

Answer (score 0):

If the code needs to be "different" then you could link your app to all the different libraries. In the end the .NET will load an assembly only when it is needed by a method (or by a class that has some fields).

Comment: That wont work customers with sql server 2008 shouldn't need to have the other dlls on there system.   These dlls have to Live in GAC

Comment: @DaImTo thanks to "delay load" the .NET won't load the dll unless they are used. I even wrote it in the response *In the end the .NET will load an assembly only when it is needed by a method*. If you have a `DoSomething2008()` and a `DoSomething2012()` that use the different assemblies then you shouldn't have any problem. There is no "pre-check" done by .NET to see if all the assemblies that could be needed are present.